# Allauth Custom Provider URLs

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Where/how does one hook up a custom provider URL patterns?

I can't find anywhere in the code that automatically installs the providers... e.g. `allauth.socialaccount.providers.shopify` URLs.

My custom provider worked on older versions like 0.2x.x but now I am getting reversal errors in the provider list template because the URLs are not registered

Comment: Why the downvote without comment?

Comment: It looks like [`allauth.urls`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/a523e1b7522d283f97fb55b783dfd3fde33a2d49/allauth/urls.py#L15) loops through the providers and registers the URLs.

Comment: @Alasdair If you want to put that in an answer I will accept otherwise I am going to delete this question as it is fairly straightforward.  Not sure how I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allauth [installation instructions](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) ask you to include `allauth.urls` in your URL conf.

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Then, in [`allauth.urls`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/a523e1b7522d283f97fb55b783dfd3fde33a2d49/allauth/urls.py#L15), the code loops through the providers and registers the provider urls. You don't have to hook up the provider url patterns manually.

Comment: Thanks... my issue was a python3 import error caught by the try block but this answers the question as asked.

Comment: Please negate the downvote on my question since you answered it =)